# What is the difference between a Time Out and a Heart Beat in AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am using the call back pattern in AWS Step Functions, and I am investigating the difference between the key "timeout" and "heartbeat" in AWS Step Functions.

CDK Code:

```
  queue: sqsStack.queue,
  heartbeat: Duration.minutes(15),
  timeout: Duration.minutes(25),
```

What are the differences, and are there best practises?

Comment: Generally a heartbeat is to notify that the worker is still responding and not dead. The timeout is how long you allow the worker to take. The two are quite unrelated.

Answer (score 7):

Timeout ([TimeoutSeconds or TimeoutSecondsPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html#task-state-example)) tells Step Functions the maximum time to wait for the task to complete. If your task does exceed this time, it will fail with a [States.Timeout error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html). You can handle this with Catch or Retry in your Task Definition. It is best practice to set this in order to avoid a workflow execution becoming stuck (i.e. if the component responsible for completing these fails). But you should avoid setting too short and consider how long this might be expected to run for under failure conditions where you don't want the workflow execution itself to fail.

Hearbeats are optional but a best practice to implement if you can. This requires you to implement heartbeats in the component that handles the tasks where it responds back to Step Functions using the [SendTaskHeartbeat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskHeartbeat.html) API action at regular intervals while it is executing the task. When you do this, you can set a Heartbeat timeout (HearbeatSeconds or HearbeatSecondsPath) that is shorter than the Task timeout and Step Functions will fail the task with a States.HeartbeatTimeout error if a SendTaskHearbeat is not received for longer than this duration. This allows you to differentiate when a task is taking a long time to complete because the responsible component is still working on it (i.e. heartbeats are received regularly) vs when the responsible component has failed (i.e. no heartbeats received). When you use heartbeats, you can more safely set a longer task timeout and avoid delays in executions when the responsible component fails silently.